# Returned data with node js and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

When i connect with mysql ,i get this value { id: 14 }
actually i wanna get only 14
this is my code

```
app.get('/register',function(req,res){
    var data = {
        "error":1,
        "result":""
    };

    console.log("ams");
    connection.query("SELECT id from register",function(err, rows, fields){
        if(rows.length != 0){
            data["error"] = 0;
            data["result"] = rows;
            res.json(data);
            console.log(data.result[0]);
        }else{
            data["result"] = 'No data Found..';
            res.json(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you expect only one result?

Comment: yes sure i wanna get value 14

Comment: yes, but it is simply the json data notation... can't you just read the json and see what is the value of the key "id"?

Comment: the value is 14 but i do not want to get the key every time
i just want the value to access it later

Comment: dear @amrhashem, the Michael's solution  you have accepted, is the same thing I have written here.

Comment: thank you piero 
it also working with me

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting one row only, you could set

```
data["result"] = rows[0].id;
```

However, your response is an array of json objects no matter how many results you get. It's much better to setup the `res.json()` receiver to work with objects, not plain strings/numbers.

It is not possible to get only values as a mysql query result in node with node-mysql (and I don't think there's any other library that would do that, because it doesn't make sense).

Comment: i get this value
{
  "error": 0,
  "result": 14
}
but i want just the value not the key

Comment: Then why do you set it in the first place? Return `res.json(rows[0].id)` if you're only interested in the value.